# How to update company's MacBook Pro with OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

How a company I work for should update my MacBook Pro to Lion? I have some options but I'm unsure which way to go?

**Note:** volume license is not an option (not that many Macs at my company).

1. Update to Lion using my Apple ID and ask for reimbursement. Cons: not
   quite the right thing IMO as license is on myself then. Pro: pricing (€23.99)
2. Ask company to buy an USB stick with update. Pros: seems the
   easiest way. Cons: pricing is at €59.99, so the company may not be willing to go that way when the update is cheaper in App Store.
3. Maybe a company can update via App Store by logging in with
   company's Apple ID?

What you recommend? What's your experience?

Comment: Who owns the computer and who will own the OS - you or the company you work for?

Comment: @Mark: The company owns the MBP, so it will own the OS licence as well. Or maybe I can own the OS licence, but how I take it with me when e.g. I leave the company?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The company should have an Apple ID set up. I would recommend that this is registered to a member of the IT team who is most responsible for software purchasing.

Then they can download OS X Lion from the app store, and have the license.

Is there a business requirement to be running Lion or is this user preference?

Comment: It's both - a requirement and preference (mostly stay up to date with latest tools for iOS dev, productivity etc.). Anyway, I you're right about setting up AID for IT and run it through their dept. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, that way they still handle everything, including any problems, if you get any.